# How to install vagrant plugin locally

Tags: vagrant

I want to make vagrant work with corporate proxy, that why I believe I need to install `vagrant-proxyconf`

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf
```

which failed with

```
Vagrant failed to load a configured plugin source. This can be caused
by a variety of issues including: transient connectivity issues, proxy
filtering rejecting access to a configured plugin source, or a configured
plugin source not responding correctly. Please review the error message
below to help resolve the issue:

  Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Failed to open TCP connection to api.rubygems.org:443 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) for "api.rubygems.org" port 443) (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Source: https://rubygems.org/
```

fair enough, while I'm behind the proxy. So I thought I can download in via browser and retry, so I have local vagrant-proxyconf-1.5.2.gem and I tried

```
vagrant plugin install ./vagrant-proxyconf-1.5.2.gem
```

and it failed with

```
  Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Failed to open TCP connection to api.rubygems.org:443 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) for "api.rubygems.org" port 443) (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Source: https://rubygems.org/
```

ok, seems like a dependency, so I downloaded specs.4.8.gz and I tried again, but same problem

```
  Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Failed to open TCP connection to api.rubygems.org:443 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) for "api.rubygems.org" port 443) (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

...so I tried with

```
  vagrant plugin install specs.4.8 --plugin-source file://c:/betlista/downloads
```

and same problem again

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Failed to open TCP connection to api.rubygems.org:443 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) for "api.rubygems.org" port 443) (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I'm on Windows 10 and Vagrant version is 2.1.0. I'm very new to Vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

execute these commands in a Windows Terminal

set http_proxy=http://proxy....net:port

set https_proxy=http://proxy.....net:port